# How to write while-loop in spring

Tags: spring, while-loop

I have a test here, where I try a loop at the last assert. My point is, that I need to do while loop till .hasNoRoles(); is true
Can you please help me with how to write this while loop. Thank you :)

```
  @Test
  public void deleteAssignedRoleTest() {
    /* Create new unique role */
    String idRole = roleExtApi.postRoles(DefaultModelFactory.createRole()).getBody().getIdRole();

    /* Create unique identity with assigned role */
    IdentityAssignment identityAssignment = roleExtApi.postIdentityAssignments(DefaultModelFactory.createIdentityAssignment(idRole)).getBody();
    assertThat(identityAssignment)
        .isNotNull()
        .hasRoles(idRole);

    /* Delete assigned role */
    ResponseEntity<Void> response = roleExtApi.deleteRoles(idRole);
      Assertions.assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);

    /* Identity does not have assigned role anymore */
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      assertThat(roleExtApi.getIdentityAssignments(identityAssignment.getIdIdentity()))
          .hasNoRoles();
  }
```

Comment: Just replace your `for` loop with the `while` loop, what's the problem?

Comment: And why do you expect for `roleExtApi.getIdentityAssignments` to change its output inside your loop?

Comment: I am sorry I am a beginner in Java, so I just don't know how to write it. This is my problem :) 


It just because that distributed update takes some time (roughly 300 ms) and I don't want to use "sleep" So I would like to use a while loop.

Comment: @JanaHajná Is there a reason for not using Thread.sleep()? It looks like there is a small interval needed between roleExtApi.deleteRoles() and the next call.